# Help with functions and relations?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

I'm currently doing work on discrete mathematics in my free time and am having some difficulties with understanding some questions pertaining to Relations and Functions. To be specific, I'm stuck on the following practice question:

> We have a relation $R$ on $\mathbb{Z}+$ defined as follows: $mRn$ if and only if $m|n$, with $A = \{ 1,2,4,13,26,52 \}$
>
> 1. Determine the set $B = \{n ∈ \mathbb{Z} \ | \ 52Rn \}$.
> 2. Indicate whether $A \cap B = \varnothing$.

Would the answer to (1) just be all integers that are divisible by 52?

As for (2) I'm unable to answer because I do not have the set $B$.

Any help is greatly appreciated!
Thank you.

Comment: I believe that $B$ is as defined in part a.  I agree with your determination of $A$ with the proviso that it should just be the positive integers divisible by $52$ (at least that's how I read the $\mathbb Z^+$ in the definition.

Comment: Answer to a.: All positive integers divisible by 52, since your relation is defined only on $\mathbb{Z}^+$. So answer to b. is non empty.

Answer (score 1):

a) Note it is 52Rn, and not nR52.  So it would be all the integers that 52 divides into.  In other words all the multiples of 52.

b) A intersect B = all the multiples of 52 in A.  Which is {52}.  So it isn't empty.